# Can I link to the middle of a post?

Tags: feature-request, links

I want to add a Wikipedia-style index to [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/12525/3927) post. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do that, which Wikipedia employs, is with HTML code called an ID attribute.

The way it generally works is that they wrap text in an [HTML element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element) called a span. It looks like this:

`<span>Some text here</span>`.

They make it so you can link to it by giving the span an ID [attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_attribute), like this:

`<span id="section-to-link-to">Article text goes here</span>`

Then they link to it with a link like `wikipedia.org/Article_title#section-to-link-to`. The # sign lets the browser know to look for a span* with the ID "section-to-link-to" on that page.

I gave this a quick try on the article that you're looking at, but Bicycles SE just ignored the HTML. (There are good reasons for this, but they're too technical to go into here.) There **may** be a way to override that, but I'm guessing the mods would need to get involved. There may also be a completely different way to do that on SE sites that I'm not aware of.

*You can actually give almost any, if not all, HTML elements an ID and this will work. Wikipedia just happens to use `span`.

Comment: It'd be better to add `id="..."` to an `h1` or `h2`, rather than a `span`, but SE's code will strip those anyways. Mods can't override that. SE developers would need to do something about it. Changing this question from `support` to `feature-request` should get the right SE people's attention. Since it could be abused (even accidentally) to mess up the page display and isn't a common request, it seems unlikely to happen, though. Maybe convince SE to automatically add ids to in-post headers, instead, like 869-1 for first header in post 869?